# How to reference images and fonts in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have recently started using WordPress and am wanting to make sure I am referencing my images and fonts correctly. When I referenced my css file I used the wp_enqueue_style function, given that you do not reference the CSS file directly I was wondering if there is specific way that I should be referencing images and fonts.

Currently for my header/logo I have done this

```
<img src="http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/toplogo.png";></img>
```

This is the link I was given after uploading the image to the media section of the admin panel. Have I done this correctly, also when it comes to local fonts how should I go about that?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Perpetua;  
    src: local('Museo300-Regular'), 
        url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');  
    font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS references a folder called "fonts" in the current directory, and the current directory in the eyes of this CSS file is the theme folder. If that fonts folder exists, your @font-face rule will work fine.

---

For your header image, do the following:

1. In functions.php, add `add_theme_support('custom-header');`
2. `<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" />`
3. Now, go to Appearance > Customize in the admin area, and you can set
   the header image. Now it can be changed from Wordpress and you never
   have to hard code the src should you wish to change it in the
   future.

Source: [add_theme_support](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#custom-header)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. However, in the future I may need to add other images to the site (e.g. social media links), how would I go about referencing these?

Comment: Follow JohnD's answer for that one.

Answer (score 1):

For images, you can use the [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function. Here is an example from the docs:

```
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = 8 );
if ( $image_attributes ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```